# First use of super-slow zoom in horror films to create tension

Tags: first-appearance, cinematography, horror

Here I'm not talking specifically about a "[dolly zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom)", first introduced by cinematographer Irmin Roberts in Hitchcock's *Vertigo*, but about the agonizingly slow zoom that you see not infrequently in horror movies, utilized to build tension.

(It's agonizing because you're on the edge of your seat, waiting for some reveal, and the slower the zoom, the greater the tension.)

When did its use arise in the horror genre? The question arose because I recently watched *Doctor Sleep* and noticed it during the Kubrick-homage shots, then watched *Under the Skin* (2014), which was also heavily influenced by Kubrick, and noticed the shot.  And, I suspect that if I reviewed many of the better horror films, I'd notice even more uses.

I'm asking because I'm not a horror film scholar and wondering if this did derive from Kubrick with *The Shining*, or some less well known director and film known mainly to scholars of the genre.